# How to serialize numeric data into char*

Tags: c++

I have a need to serialize `int, double, long, and float`
into a character buffer and this is the way I currently do it

```
int value = 42;
char* data = new char[64];
std::sprintf(data, "%d", value);

// check
printf( "%s\n", data );
```

First I am not sure if this is the best way to do it but my immediate problem is determining the size of the buffer.
 The number 64 in this case is purely arbitrary.
How can I know the exact size of the passed numeric so I can allocate exact memory; not more not less than is required?

Either a C or C++ solution is fine.

EDIT
Based on Johns answer ( allocate large enough buffer ..)  below, I am thinking of doing this

```
char *data = 0;
int value = 42;
char buffer[999];
std::sprintf(buffer, "%d", value);
data = new char[strlen(buffer)+1];
memcpy(data,buffer,strlen(buffer)+1);

printf( "%s\n", data );
```

Avoids waste at a cost of speed perhaps. And does not entirely solve the potential overflow
 Or could I just use the max value sufficient to represent the type.

Comment: It doesn't look like it's a standard function but `asprintf`, if available, looks like it may solve your problem well.

Comment: @Bala: that will give you the size *in memory*, he is asking about the size of the output given by sprintf to allocate a buffer big enough.

Comment: Do you really want to serialize numeric data lexically? At least you could store the precise binary value, perhaps Base64-encoded. That has a definite size, too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In C++ you can use a string stream and stop worrying about the size of the buffer:

```
#include <sstream>

...

std::ostringstream os;
int value=42;
os<<42; // you use string streams as regular streams (cout, etc.)
std::string data = os.str(); // now data contains "42"
```

(If you want you can get a `const char *` from an `std::string` via the `c_str()` method)

---

In C, instead, you can use the `snprintf` to "fake" the write and get the size of the buffer to allocate; in facts, if you pass 0 as second argument of `snprintf` you can pass `NULL` as the target string and you get the characters that would have been written as the return value. So in C you can do:

```
int value = 42;
char * data;
size_t bufSize=snprintf(NULL, 0 "%d", value)+1; /* +1 for the NUL terminator */
data = malloc(bufSize);
if(data==NULL)
{
    // ... handle allocation failure ...
}
snprintf(data, bufSize, "%d", value);
// ...
free(data);
```

Comment: This is definitely a valid approach and I have used it but then I thought that was too many hoops: First ostringstream then call to str() then call to c_str() then finally call to strcpy to populate the buffer.

Comment: @luis: I expanded the answer, have a look at the second method. By the way, what is the "final destination" of this data? Maybe you can avoid some of the extra steps of the C++ solution...

Comment: Boost.lexical_cast wraps up all those hoops quite nicely.

Comment: @Matteo Italia The 'final destination' is char* data which is a member of a class that is managing the buffer.

Comment: @luis: maybe the buffer itself should be an `std::string` (if it's supposed to contain only text), but if you don't want to change that the second solution should be your best bet.

Comment: @Matteo Italia Is there a way to implement your second solution in C++. I am worried about that free(data) at the end. But I think it is a clever approach

Comment: @luis: The first approach is the vastly superior one.

Comment: @luis: you can make the second solution exception-safe by using a smart pointer like `boost::scoped_array`; if you want it to be more C++-ish you should start to use `std::string`, but then you could just use the first solution (and I would use it unless in case of serious performance problems).

Comment: @Matteo Italia Actually I think your second solution is not as dangerous as I initially thought. char* data is managed inside a class so it will be freed.

Comment: @luis: still, if you use that code in C++ keep an eye on that pointer (e.g. using a smart pointer) to avoid leaking memory in case of exception.

Answer (score -2):

I would serialize to a 'large enough' buffer then copy to an allocated buffer. In C

```
char big_buffer[999], *small_buffer;
sprintf(big_buffer, "%d", some_value);
small_buffer = malloc(strlen(big_buffer) + 1);
strcpy(small_buffer, big_buffer);
```

Comment: This is interesting. I am going to try a C++ approach using the same technique

Comment: Taking no chances with your temporary buffer being too small, eh?

Comment: How do you determine what's "large enough"?  It's possible, in principle, that `int` could be big enough to overflow a 999-byte buffer, though of course that's unlikely.  More realistically, there are ways to compute a much smaller upper bound, but it's non-trivial to do it well at compile time.

Comment: @DeadMG Magic is what I resort to when I don't know the correct answer ;-)

Comment: -1 could lead to hard to find bugs, and there are much better methods.

Comment: @Ethan, I'd be interested to know how the 'hard to find bugs' could arise, and what the 'much better methods' are.

Comment: @john: Oops I forgot to count the upper limit on "int", which happens to be about 20 chars, so it could not lead to "bugs". Still a better way would be to find the size of the string and then allocate a sufficient buffer, look at the answer above you.

Comment: @Ethan: snprintf is good in theory, trouble is that the Microsoft implementation deviates from the standard so I'm reluctant to recommend it.